# IE truncating URL?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, url, truncate

I have a url (HTTP) that gets redirected.

This is the end of the url with paramters:

```
/c.html?ufl=c&rtr=on&s=x9w5pl,33gz,2cw,75vq,lelf,gwtv,jxou&RESNET_CODE=FIE&OFFERCODE=H38FR10
```

When I use chrome to GET this url, the original url gets redirected to a url (HTTPS) that ends like this:

```
/cgi-bin/LANSAWEB?procfun+rn+Resnet+FIE+funcparms+UP(A2560):;H38FR10;?/#
```

However, when I use IE (I'm testing with version 8)), it somehow drops the last parameter and the url (HTTPS) looks like this:

```
/cgi-bin/LANSAWEB?procfun+rn+Resnet+FIE+funcparms+UP(A2560):
```

I have used fiddler to determine that both Chrome and IE are posting the same Get request (as shown above):

```
/c.html?ufl=c&rtr=on&s=x9w5pl,33gz,2cw,75vq,lelf,gwtv,jxou&RESNET_CODE=FIE&OFFERCODE=H38FR10
```

Why in the world is the last parameter `;H38FR10;?/#` being truncated when I use IE???

I would add that if I take the url that chrome gets redirected to, and put it in IE, it works!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meta refresh with semicolon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124170/meta-refresh-with-semicolon)

Answer (score 0):

Your markup was:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://HOSTNAMEHERE/cgi-bin/LANSAWEB?procfun+rn+Resnet+FIE+funcparms+UP(A2560):;H38FR10;?/#">
 </head></html>
```

The problem here is that the META tag’s CONTENT values are separated by semicolons.

If you change your markup to wrap the URL in single quotes, it works in IE:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='https://HOSTNAMEHERE/cgi-bin/LANSAWEB?procfun+rn+Resnet+FIE+funcparms+UP(A2560):;H38FR10;?/#'">
```

There are good reasons not to use a META REFRESH (as I discuss [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/meta-refresh-causes-additional-http-requests.aspx)). If you cannot use a HTTP/301 or HTTP/302 redirect, you should consider using a SCRIPT block to navigate to the URL if script is enabled, and moving the META into a NOSCRIPT block.

This question appears to be a duplicate: [Meta refresh with semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124170/meta-refresh-with-semicolon) and offers a workaround.

Comment: Ok I sent the file. Thanks!

Comment: Just added a comment...if I take the url that chrome gets redirected to, and put it in IE, it works!

Answer (score 0):

A colon is a special character in a URL, so you should escape it, ie convert it to the URL-encoded string `%3A`.

In theory it shouldn't be a problem to have a colon in this part of the URL, but it wouldn't be a surprise for IE8 to have an issue with it.

Comment: Well...the problem is, if I take the url that chrome gets redirected to, and put it in IE, it works!

Comment: Well, old IE versions are nothing if not inconsistent. Have you tried it with URL encoding? Did it make a difference?